# How can I listen to Firestore documents that are created with a non existing field and set a default value in Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### Context

I am trying to listen for new client accounts that do not have a privacy field set during account creation on the client side (the default privacy set on the client side is coming in the next update)

### Main question

non existing document fields that are printed to the Firebase console are `undefined` am I able to compare a variable to a non existing field like this `privacy===null`

Also, please let me know if there is a better way to structure this type of function.

```
export const listenForPrivacyNullAccounts = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const { uid } = context.params
      const data = snapshot.data()

      const privacy = data.isPrivate

      if(privacy===null){
        const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid)
        const res = await userRef.set({
          isPrivate: false
        }, { merge: true })
        return res
      } else {
        return null
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is not added / present in the queried document you will get `undefined`; In that case, you could do the update by checking the value is `undefined`.

But if you have intentionally passed `null` for that field while creating the document, you should follow your current snippet. That checks only the value is null or not.

In typescript, the simple check shall be defined by using [nullish coallesing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing)

```
   const privacy = data.isPrivate ?? false
```

Here the `privacy` is `false` only if the `data.isPrivate` field is null or undefined